# Out of process COM server execution

Tags: delphi, com

I've turned an ancient, but still useful, Delphi 5 application into an out of process COM server. I vaguely recall that there's a way to tell if it's started directly by a user or as the server. I know I've done it before, but I can't remember/find how to do it. A command line switch, maybe?

Comment: "Started directly by the user" == ?

Comment: @pst Executed from the windows shell, like a regular application.

Comment: @Suresh. I didn't add delphi as a tag because I'm pretty sure the answer has nothing to do with delphi specifically, but rather behaviour specific to COM.

Comment: I don't think that there is, as I tried to do this before.  DCOM process activation would probably start your app with the same Win32 calls as Explorer.  So unless you added a "/DesktopShortcut" param to your icons when you created them in your installer, I doubt you can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know whether this was available in Delphi 5, but in Delphi 2010 you can query the global ComServer object for the start mode:

```
if ComServer.StartMode = smAutomation then
  ShowMessage('started as automation server')
else if ComServer.StartMode = smStandalone then
  ShowMessage('started manually');
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. The code in `TComServer.Create` checks the command line for the `/embedding` or `/automation` switches. And if found then `StartMode` is set to `smAutomation`. Other possible start modes are `smStandalone`, `smRegServer` and `smUnregServer`.

Comment: It is indeed available in Delphi 5.

Comment: The COM object's registration specifies the command-line parameters that are passed to the EXE when it is started by COM.  Most COM implementations specify '/automation' as part of that registration for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Remy, I thought I was never gonna learn the answer. :)

Comment: The ComServer.StartMode implementation checks the command line switches. Told you it was a switch.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the exe is started with the switch "-Embedding" when started as a COM server.

Comment: I just ran up a quick demo myself, logging the command line at startup and "-Embedding" is indeed added as a command line switch (Delphi 7 on Win 7)